# image disappears when changing height in % vs vw in CSS

Tags: html, css

Im busy designing my portfolio website and I have some images that I want to be able to scale correctly to the size of the browser or device. I have been messing around with vw and it seems to solve the problem quite nicely. However due to being a student im looking at making sure the code is solid in that it wont be affected on different browsers or devices.

So the main problem here is when I use % on one image to adjust the height, the image dissapears completely. I can only make it appear in the correct position using either px or vw and was trying to find out why? (Take note I am only needing to adjust the height, id like to be able to use % otherwise I end up with a huge gap when scaling it down to smaller devices and browsers)

Here is my CSS:

```
/*----------------------------Top ----------------------------*/
.topwrap{
    position:relative;
    top:50px;
}
.face{
    position:relative;
    float:right;
    background:url(../images/face2.png) no-repeat;
    background-size:100%;
    top:10%;
    width:50%;
    height:15vw;
    right:16%;
    min-width:160px;
}
.txtwrap{
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:1.3%;
    font-size:1.3vw;
    float:right;                
    right:39%;  
    text-align: center;
}
.sptxt{ 
    color:#171717;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.sptxt2{    
    color:#171717;
    font-weight:400;
}
/*----------------------------Lower----------------------------*/
.lowerwrap{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    height:100%;
    width:100%; 
    top:50px;
    padding-top:10px;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px #333 inset;    
}
.contentwrap{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:15vw;
    background:url(../images/content.png) no-repeat;
    background-size:100%;
    display: block;
    z-index:1;
}
```

Comment: Have you considered flex? You can align things neatly with it. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/   you may be interested in align-items:stretch

Comment: that seems to have done the trick. Is there any specific way you would use it?

Comment: You will find times when it is useful, and other times when it may be a hassle. I judge on a per project basis. Sorry, I cannot answer as the answer always changes. I just wanted you to know the options available to you so you could decide.

Comment: Yea i tried applying it to another image with vw and the image still vanished  so trying to fogure it out

Answer (score 0):

```
body{ font-size: 16px }
@media screen and (max-width: XXXpx) {body { font-size: 12px } }
@media screen and (max-width: XXXpx) {body { font-size: 8px } }
```

for the rest of your code, such as padding, margin you can use em/rem, 
if will scale well, according to the font-size of body; that way your "GAP" between image will resize as well.